# Передача имени формы

Tags: php, html

Есть список с жанрами музыки, в зависимости от нажатой кнопки выводится музыка определенного жанра, но так как жанров много, то не хочется для каждого жанра писать свою выборку. Может быть, можно как-то передавать в обработчик имя формы и потом сравнивать имя с жанром в таблице и выводить?

Вот пара форм:

```
<form method="POST" action="music.php">
<input type = "submit" name="soul" value="Soul">
</form>
<br>
<form method="POST" action="music.php">
<input type = "submit" name="vokal" value="Вокальная">
</form>
<br>
<form method="POST" action="music.php">
<input type = "submit" name="jaz" value="Джаз">
</form>

if(isset($_POST['bluz'])) {
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `music` WHERE `Жанр` = 'bluz' ");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
if ($row['Ссылка'] != ""&&file_exists("music/".$row['Ссылка'])) 
{ 
$muz='music/'.$row['Ссылка']; 

echo'<div id="spisok_pesen"><ul><li><h3>'.$row['Название'].'</h3><audio src='.$muz.' controls></audio></li></ul></div>';
}}}
if(isset($_POST['heavy'])) {
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `music` WHERE `Жанр` = 'heavy' ");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
if ($row['Ссылка'] != ""&&file_exists("music/".$row['Ссылка'])) 
{ 
$muz='music/'.$row['Ссылка']; 

echo'<div id="spisok_pesen"><ul><li><h3>'.$row['Название'].'</h3><audio src='.$muz.' controls></audio><p><a href="'.$muz.'" download><br>Скачат</a></li></ul></div>';
}}}
```

Comment: Можно и нужно передавать куда угодно и что угодно. Но по вашему вопросу даже не понятно где это вам надо сделать на клиентской стороне или на сервере. приведите пример кода и html разметки что бы было понятно о чем идет речь. (прямо в тексте вопроса, там есть ссылочка 'править')

Comment: ООП попробуйте использовать

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
mysql_query ("set_client='utf8'"); 
mysql_query ("set character_set_results='utf8'"); 
mysql_query ("set collation_connection='utf8_general_ci'"); 
mysql_query ("SET NAMES utf8"); 
ini_set('display_errors','On'); 
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT); 
$db="syte"; 
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "")or die; 
mysql_select_db($db);
$genre = mysql_query("SELECT `Жанр` FROM `music`");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($genre)){
    echo '<div id="spisok_janrov">
 <form method="POST" action="music.php">
        <input type="submit" name="'.$row['Жанр']. '" value="'.$row['Жанр'].'" />
    </form>
    <br />
</td>
</div>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно жанру назначить переменную и выводить нужные формы в цикле, к примеру:

> Страница с формами:

```
<?php
$genre = mysql_query("SELECT `Жанр` FROM `music`");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($genre)){
    echo '<form method="POST" action="music.php"><input type="submit" name="genre" value="' . $row['Жанр'] . '" /></form><br>';
}
?>
```

> Обработчик:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['genre'])) {
    $genre = $_POST['genre'];
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `music` WHERE `Жанр` = '$genre' ");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        if ($row['Ссылка'] != "" && file_exists("music/" . $row['Ссылка'])){
            $muz = 'music/' . $row['Ссылка']; 
            echo '<div id="spisok_pesen"><ul><li><h3>' . $row['Название'] . '</h3><audio src=' . $muz . ' controls></audio></li></ul></div>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Ещё можно на странице с формами сразу проверять, есть ли хоть одна песня в жанре и выводить форму только если есть. Могу где-то ошибаться в коде, так как в php я ещё не гуру, но смысл думаю понятен.

Comment: Я не совсем понял как каждой кнопке присвоить определенный жанр.

Comment: А,тю. Там же цикл сам присваивает формам жанр

Comment: Правда что-то не хочет оно работать

Comment: Я с мобильного и не могу проверить работоспособность на примере, но пытаюсь подать общую картину, код доработайте сами

Comment: Вот я переделал код, но теперь оно выводит жанр только тот, который последний в списке.

Comment: @Андрей я поправил код в первом ответе, должно работать!

Comment: Нет, не работает.

Comment: А нет, всё работает. Спасибо. Буду щас думать как сортировать формы по алфавиту :]

Comment: @Андрей добавь в конец запроса в БД `order by \`жанр\` ` - должно сортировать по алфавиту